# call a function from a header file

Tags: c, function, macros, header

I have a question regarding header files in C. I need to initialize a variable but depending on a condition. In order to evaluate that condition I need to call a function, see code below:

I have the following function-like-macro in header.h where I need to call function():

```
#define func_like_macro()   do{\
                                 if((function()==290))\
                                 {\
                                    macro(x, 0);\
                                 }\
                                 else\
                                 {\
                                    macro(x, 1);\
                                 }\
                                 macro(w, 1);\
                                 macro(z, 1);\

                              }while(0);
```

Is this correct?

I mean will this work, or shouldn't I include at all a function call inside the function-like-macro that is in a header file?

Thanks and I apologize in advance if this is a very silly question!

Comment: You do not call functions from headers. Headers are used for declaring include files and static variables/definitions. I do not think it is even valid to include non-static variables in a header file.

Comment: This is not a call "from a header". It's a header that defines a macro. When that macro is *used*, in a non-header, it will generate a call at that point. It's also rather scary. :)

Comment: In what you've shown, you're *not* calling a function from a header file; you're just defining a macro.

Comment: @Javia1492: Nit-pick: Actually, even an implementation file (`.c`) does not _call_ a function. This is done by the CPU at run-time. Less nit-picky: you very well define inline-functions in a header file and that might very well "call" other functions ...

Comment: @Javia1492 There's nothing stopping you having code in a header file that calls a function (or for that matter does anything else) except convention. #include copies the contents of the header file (or any other file) to the top of your file before compiling.

Comment: For the "funky do {} while()" to make sense, you at least have to remove the semicolon from `}while(0);` -->> `}while(0)`

Comment: @JamesSnook Which is why you cannot use a function that is modifying a non-static variable in the header. However, OP has not clarified whether this variable is modified again later or not so this may just be nothing more than an assumption of how he is using it.

Comment: @Javia1492: Why that? It can very well modify any variable in its scope or accessible through a pointer in its scope.

Comment: @Olaf You mean by reference? You can do that. But, i've always had compiler errors when trying declare non-static variables in my headers.

Comment: No, by a pointer. C does not have references in its actual meaning (hiding the pointer semantics). Note that non-static variables includes auto variables. Could you please be more precise? Just that: A _declaration_ will do no harm. Actually, a header file is the place for all global declarations. The _definition_ is a different subject. Of these only `inline` function definitions belong into a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have a initializer function? Normally, you will not use many global variables, so that would not be much of a problem. And for local variables, you'd need that anyways.

For the original question: A macro is just a text replacement. It is performed *before* the C compiler executes. Think of it as advanced text-replacement in the editor, so the function call in the macro will be inserted whereever you use that macro.

In general, function-like macros should be avoided. `inline` functions are often a much better approach. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Inline.html#Inline) is a good rationalen not only for gcc.

Note that if you intended the variable to be initialized that way at compile-time will not work anyway. As I already nit-picked in a comment to your question, the function is actually called at run-time, never at compile-time. Therefore this macro will not help. Worse: this will not even  compile, as the compiler has no idea when to call that function. Note that C has no constructors/destructors like c++ and other OOPLs.

Comment: Hi all, Thank you for your answers. I should have probably explained it better. The func_like_macro() is called from within a .c file in order to initialize the variables x,w and z. My concern is whether it would actually work calling the function ((function()==290)) within the func_like_macro which is in the header file. Also, even if it works, is it something I shouldn't do?

Comment: I think I detailed that good enough in my answer. You actually do not gain any advantage compared to a function, but loose much of code-quality/safety. So: nothing gained, much lost. The decission should be clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I kind of can't change the function-like-macro because it is code that was already in place and there are a lot of things that depend on it. In my case, what I needed to do was to change the initialization value of variable x, which is actually a micro port, based on the value returned by function(). So I was concern that the making a function call within the function-like-macro was not going to work. Now, I understand that this is not good quality code but at least it works.